# MATLAB - How do I find the first integer of an infinite set that satisfies this condition?

Tags: matlab, find, primes

I want to find the smallest integer `P`,  such that the number of primes in the set `{1,2,..., P}` is less than `P/6`.

I think have the answer via (long) trial and error but would like to know how to verify this through MATLAB.

Comment: I assume that you are looking for the first P: P > 1, since {1} contains no primes and 0 < 1/6.

Comment: I did put that, must've got changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isprime` to check if any value in an array is a prime number. If we want to check all integers up until the integer `N` we can do

```
% You can change this to the maximum number that you'd like to consider for P
N = 2000;

possible_P_values = 2:N;                % We omit 1 here since it's not a prime number
primes = isprime(possible_P_values);
```

To determine how many primes have occured up to a given integer `N` we can use `cumsum` of this logical matrix (the cumulative sum)

```
nPrimes_less_than_or_equal_to_P = cumsum(primes);
```

Then we can divide `possible_P_values` by 6 and check where the number of primes up to a certain point is less than that number.

```
is_less_than_P_over_6 = nPrimes_less_than_or_equal_to_P < (possible_P_values ./ 6);
```

Then we can identify the first occurance with `find`

```
possible_P_values(find(is_less_than_P_over_6, 1, 'first'))
%   1081
```

Comment: Excellent. Very helpful and clearly explained - thanks so much!